# Selenium WebDriver python: checkbox cannot click, default the checkbox is invisible and when hover it can be visible

Tags: python, selenium, checkbox

all

I am now testing Onedrive(onedrive.live.com)and want to simulate the checkbox as following screenshot:
(I am a new comer and cannot post image due to need at least 10 reputation. Sorry! )

In default the checkbox is invisible, when mouse hover the file and it will be visible, and click it.   I use Selenium to simulate the whole action but fails, and some code snippet shows below:

```
elem1=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="c-SetItemTile "]')
hover=ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(elem1[6])
hover.perform()
driver.implicitly_wait(3)


elem2=elem1[6].find_element_by_tag_name("input")

#WebDriverWait(driver,60).until(lambda driver :  elem2.is_displayed())

print elem2.tag_name
print elem2.get_attribute("id")
if elem2.is_displayed():
    elem2.click()
else:
    print "not checked!!!"
```

Note: when I use WebDriverWait for waiting the checkbox is visible, but it seems that it always is invisible.

Anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If there is a find by class option in Selenium(I know there is one in splinter) then try doing find_element_by_class_name("selectArea") (or whatever you would use in Selenium to find elements on a page) The box just checks your cursors position and if that is in the select area and you click it will count that as checked. I hope that makes sense.